# Creating a custom vector class. Push_back function only working for the first value

Tags: c++, arrays, class, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

In my Comp Sci class, we are learning how to make our own vector class. We will eventually store our custom made string class objects in a custom made vector class. I wanted to try and build a vector class of integers beforehand for simplicity.

So far, I have a default constructor that initializes my pointer to an empty array and sets the size to 0. Then I try to append some values using my push_back function and then check to make sure it was done correctly.

When I do std::cout << v[0] << std::endl;

I get the correct output (10). However, if I call push_back again and then call v[1] I get 0.

I feel like I am not allocating memory correctly in my push_back function but I am not sure.

Thanks for any advice!

[part 1][1]

[part 2][2]

sorry if my formatting is wrong I am new to posting here.

class:

```
class myVector
{
private:
    int *data; //will point to an array of ints
    size_t size; //determins the size of array
public:
    myVector(); // default constructor
    void push_back(int); // appends an integer to the vector
    int operator[](size_t);
    size_t sizeOf();
};
```

main:

```
int main()
{
    myVector v;
    v.push_back(10);
    std::cout << v.sizeOf() << std::endl;
    v.push_back(14);
    std::cout << v.sizeOf() << std::endl;
    std::cout << v[1] << std::endl;

    return 0;
```

}

member functions:

```
size_t myVector::sizeOf()
{
    return size;
}

int myVector::operator[](size_t location)
{
    return this->data[location]; //this will return the value at data + 
                                 //location
}

myVector::myVector()
{
    this->data = new int[0]; //initialize the data to an empty array of 
                             //ints
    size = 0; //initialize the size to 0
}

void myVector::push_back(int val)
{
    if(size == 0) //if size == 0, create a new array with 1 extra index
    {
        ++size;
        delete [] this->data;
        this->data = new int[size];
        this->data[0] = val;
    }
    else
    {
         ++size;
         int *temp = new int[size - 1];
         for(int i = 0; i != (size - 1); i++)
         {
              temp[i] = this->data[i];
         }
         delete [] this->data;
         this->data = new int[size];
         for(int i = 0; i != (size - 1); i++)
         {
             this->data[i] = temp[i];
         }
         this->data[size] = val;
         delete [] temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: please include a [mcve] in the question. Code as text not as images please

Comment: I apologize, trying to get the formatting correct enough to submit was annoying. But now its up!

Comment: you start with `size=0` then you increment size and allocate an array via `new int[size -1]`, thats still not big enough for 1 element.

Comment: @idclev463035818 That's actually not the problem, because there's a _second_ allocation `this->data = new int[size]` later on. There's way too many uses of `new` and `delete[]` in this code, but it's not actually causing this specific issue.

Comment: @NathanPierson oh right thanks. What is saw is just to store the elements in some temp array (for whatever reason) I just saw that and didnt read on.

Comment: @NathanPierson Would you care to enlighten me on a more efficient way to do this sort of thing?

Comment: First: I don't see any reason to allocate and immediately delete a zero-element array for the "empty" state. Second: You can just do something like `int* temp = data; data = new int[size]; ... delete[] temp;` and use your original `data` as the temporary array. Third, but hardest to fix: Copying over your entire array every time you add a new element is gross overkill compared to exponential growth reallocation strategies.

Comment: @NathanPierson Ah I see. I will try to change it based on this advice. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code:

```
this->data[size] = val;
```

you are going outside of the allocated array.

Same in the previous loop (in its last iteration):

```
 for(int i = 0; i != (size - 1); i++)
 {
     this->data[i] = temp[i];
 }
```

Comment: Thanks! taking this advice I got it to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems.

1. It does not look like you need a special case for 0 sized vector
2. you do not allocate enough memory:

Example, if size is one, you hit this case, then size becomes 2, and you allocate a buffer of ... 1.

````
else
{
     ++size;
     int *temp = new int[size - 1];
     for(int i = 0; i != (size - 1); i++)
     {
         temp[i] = this->data[i];
     }

Tip: use ```for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)```  and ```new int[size]```
````

3. you go out of bounds after your loop.  If you allocate [size] bytes, then (size-1) is the last valid index.
4. you copy data into temp, then copy temp into ANOTHER allocation.  You don't need to do that.  Just assign this->data = temp;  The whole second loop is needless, and don't delete temp at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Its not necessary to a lot of `new` and `delete` operations and loops. I fixed and cleaned your two functions.

```
myVector::myVector()
{
    this->data = new int[1]; //initialize the data to an empty array of 
                             //ints
    size = 0; //initialize the size to 0
}

void myVector::push_back(int val)
{
    if(size == 0) //if size == 0, create a new array with 1 extra index
    {
        ++size;
        this->data[0] = val;
    }
    else
    {
         ++size;
         int *temp = new int[size];
         for(int i = 0; i != (size-1); ++i)
         {
              temp[i] = this->data[i];
         }
         delete [] this->data;
         this->data = temp;
         this->data[size-1]=val;
    }
}
```

in `push_back` function allocate a new array with new size and copy data from existing array. After deleting existing array and we see `this->data` can't point to valid location. Assign the new array's address to `this->data` and we access existing data and size increased +1. Last we assign parameter `val` to end of array(size-1).